# call of overloaded 'swap(float&, float&)' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, templates, swap

in this program the calling of swap function giving an error called call of overloded function is ambiguos.please tell me how i can resolve this problem. is there is any diffrent method of calling the template function

```
     #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
      template <class T>
    void swap(T&x,T&y)
    {
            T temp;
            temp=x;
         x=y;
           y=temp;
       }
    int main()
   {
    float f1,f2;
    cout<<"enter twp float numbers: ";
    cout<<"Float 1: ";
     cin>>f1;
    cout<<"Float 2: ";
    cin>>f2;
    swap(f1,f2);
    cout<<"After swap: float 1: "<<f1<<" float 2:"<<f2;
    int a,b;
    cout<<"enter twp integer numbers: ";
    cout<<"int 1: ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"int 2: ";
    cin>>b;
    swap(a,b);
    cout<<"After swap: int 1: "<<a<<" int 2:"<<b;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: There is already std::swap function, and your function have the same name. Rename your function to something like my_swap

Comment: You are right,,,there is predefined function called swap in c++ so compiler confusing in execution.. i change the name of the method and i work...  thanks a lot :)

Comment: Also, don't use `using` to dump the entire standard library into the global namespace. We use namespaces for good reasons.

Answer (score 9):

Your function is conflicting with the one defined in `move.h` that is included implicitly by some of your includes. If you remove the `using namespace std` this should be fixed - the function you are conflicting with is defined in the `std` namespace.

Comment: i am using code block compiler to execute c++ program. if i remove the `using namespace std` it will thrown an error as cout and cin functions are proceed throught that namespace

Comment: of course it will. This is because cout and cin are in the std namespace. You can either add cluases like `using std::cin;` and `using std::cout` instead of the using namespace or use the namespace qualified names `std::cin` and `std::cout` everywhere. I strongly recommend that you read more about namespaces.

Comment: @suhas - yes, you're running into the typical problems that are caused by indiscriminately adding `using namespace std;`. Take it out, then deal with the problems that it hid. In the long run your code will be much better.

Comment: i got the infected code. actually i was using function name `swap` which is same as that of predefined function in c++. which causing an error. i change that & now it is working

Comment: Please read about namespaces. The name of your function is the name as the name of the built-in function only because of the `using namespace std` in your code. PeteBecker's comment is the right way to solve your problem and also suggests what I wrote in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

By changing the swap function to my_swap function it solve the problem. because swap is also a predefined function in c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
  template <class T>
void my_swap(T&x,T&y)
{
        T temp;
        temp=x;
     x=y;
       y=temp;
   }
int main()
{
  float f1,f2;
cout<<"enter twp float numbers: ";
cout<<"Float 1: ";
 cin>>f1;
cout<<"Float 2: ";
cin>>f2;
my_swap(f1,f2);
cout<<"After swap: float 1: "<<f1<<" float 2:"<<f2;
int a,b;
cout<<"enter twp integer numbers: ";
cout<<"int 1: ";
cin>>a;
cout<<"int 2: ";
cin>>b;
my_swap(a,b);
cout<<"After swap: int 1: "<<a<<" int 2:"<<b;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

surely, rename your function or remove -> there is one in the library already:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/

and this is what your compiler is complaining about.